# How to order a matrix by all columns

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

Ok, I'm stuck in a dumbness loop.  I've read thru the helpful ideas at [How to sort a dataframe by column(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r?rq=1) , but need one more hint.  I'd like a function that takes a matrix with an arbitrary number of columns, and sorts by all columns in sequence.  E.g., for a matrix `foo` with `N` columns,
does the equivalent of `foo[order(foo[,1],foo[,2],...foo[,N]),]` . I am happy to use a `with` or `by` construction, and if necessary define the `colnames` of my matrix, but I can't figure out how to automate the collection of arguments to `order` (or to `with`) . 
Or, I should say, I could build the entire bloody string with `paste` and then `call` it, but I'm sure there's a more straightforward way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most elegant (for certain values of "elegant") way would be to turn it into a data frame, and use `do.call`:

```
foo[do.call(order, as.data.frame(foo)), ]
```

This works because a data frame is just a `list` of variables with some associated attributes, and can be passed to functions expecting a `list`.

Comment: Thank you!  I'd been mucking with `do.call` and just plain forgot about coercing to a dataframe.